# Difficulty with pattern matching on an instance of an associated type

Tags: json, pattern-matching, rust, deserialization, type-mismatch

I am relying on `rustc_serialize` to parse JSON data into a struct, `Orders`, which represents a `Vec` of `Order` structs. The JSON data may have an array or a `null` value; my intent is to either parse the array of orders normally, if any, or parse the `null` value as an `Orders` with an empty `Vec`. If neither of these is the case, then an error is to be relayed. This is my attempt:

```
impl Decodable for Orders {
    fn decode<D: Decoder>(d: &mut D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        let try = d.read_seq(|d, l| {
            let mut orders = Vec::new();
            for _ in 0..l {
                let order = try!(Decodable::decode(d));
                orders.push(order);
            }
            Ok(Orders(orders))
        });

        match try {
            value @ Ok(_) => value,
            error @ Err(e) => match e {
                ExpectedError(_, x) if &x == "null" => Ok(Orders(Vec::new())),
                _ => error,
            },
        }
    } 
}
```

My issue has to do with pattern matching on `ExpectedError`. The compiler gives me the following error:

```
 expected `<D as rustc_serialize::serialize::Decoder>::Error`,
    found `rustc_serialize::json::DecoderError`
(expected associated type,
    found enum `rustc_serialize::json::DecoderError`) [E0308]
src/api/types/json.rs:125                 ExpectedError(_, x) if &x == "null" => Ok(Orders(Vec::new())),
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am stumped on this one. How can I correct this?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? If yes, I would highly appreciate some more details. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I correct this?

In general, you would have to choose between being generic or specialized. You cannot pattern match on an associated type because this type can be anything and a generic method should work for any type which satisfies the constraints.

For example, in your case:

- `<D as rustc_serialize::serialize::Decoder>::Error` can be *anything*
- `rustc_serialize::json::DecoderError` is but one possibility

So you should normally choose between using some abstract `D` or specializing the decoding for `json`.

---

However, since you are implementing `Decodable` here, you cannot choose NOT to be generic as you do not get to pick the signature.

Furthermore, it appears that `rustc_serialize` does not support tentative parsing (or at least, its `json` implementation does not), so I am afraid that you cannot check for nullity (using `d.read_nil()`) beforehand.

I suppose those limitations can be seen as the reason that this library is being retired in favor of [serde](https://crates.io/crates/serde/), and can only encourage you to try it out.